# Cannot display opening price data from yahoo using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

```
getSymbols("2222.SR")
[1] "2222.SR"
OPEN1<-Op(2222.SR)
Error: unexpected symbol in "OPEN1<-Op(2222.SR"
```

I was expecting R to give me the opening price but for some reason it's giving me this error although it was able to fetch that data from yahoo. BTW I'm using quantmod.

I'm a beginner at this so I have no idea what's wrong :(. This is a stock in the Saudi stock market from yahoo finance. I tried the same thing with another Saudi stock and still it didn't work I also tried other functions like for the closing price and got the same results:

```
getSymbols("7010.SR")
[1] "7010.SR"
```

> Warning message:
>
> 7010.SR contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider
> using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace
> them.

```
OPEN2<-Op(7010.SR)
Error: unexpected symbol in "OPEN2<-Op(7010.SR"
```

I also tried it with an American traded stock and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that if you use `getSymbols("2222.SR")` it creates an object called 2222.SR in your environment. But because is starts with numbers in the object name, you can't just call it with `Op("2222.SR")`. That will give you this error. You need to use backticks to access this object or tell getSymbols not to auto assign an object name.

Code with backticks:

```
library(quantmod)

# with the use of backticks
getSymbols("2222.SR")

OPEN1 <- Op(`2222.SR`)
head(OPEN1)
           2222.SR.Open
2019-12-11     29.09091
2019-12-12     31.98347
2019-12-15     30.66116
2019-12-16     30.99173
2019-12-17     31.44628
2019-12-18     30.99173
```

Code without backticks:

```
aramco <- getSymbols("2222.SR", auto.assign = FALSE)

OPEN1 <- Op(aramco)

head(OPEN1)
           2222.SR.Open
2019-12-11     29.09091
2019-12-12     31.98347
2019-12-15     30.66116
2019-12-16     30.99173
2019-12-17     31.44628
2019-12-18     30.99173
```